# Singleton. Что означает эта запись - Singleton.class

Tags: synchronized, singleton, шаблон-одиночка

Почему в блок synchronized(Singleton.class) передается Singleton.class

```
public final class Singleton {
private static volatile Singleton instance;
public String value;

private Singleton(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static Singleton getInstance(String value) {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (Singleton.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Singleton(value);
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
 }
}
```